# HTTP GET Request and content-location with respect to REST

Tags: http, rest

I have gone through the specification and I am not sure when to use `content-location` vs `location`. I am getting following response when I do HTTP GET with my rest server

```
 ResponseEntity
  <200 OK,{
    "store" : {
      "book" : [ {
        "category" : "reference",
        "author" : "Nigel Rees",
        "title" : "Sayings of the Century",
        "displayprice" : 8.95
      }, {
        "category" : "fiction",
        "author" : "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title" : "Sword of Honour",
        "displayprice" : 12.99
      }, {
        "category" : "fiction",
        "author" : "Herman Melville",
        "title" : "Moby Dick",
        "isbn" : "0-553-21311-3",
        "displayprice" : 8.99
      }, {
        "category" : "fiction",
        "author" : "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title" : "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn" : "0-395-19395-8",
        "displayprice" : 22.99
      } ],
      "bicycle" : {
        "color" : "red",
        "displayprice" : 19.95,
        "foo:bar" : "fooBar",
        "dot.notation" : "new",
        "dash-notation" : "dashes"
      }
    }
  },{Server=[Apache-Coyote/1.1], Content-Location=[http://localhost:25538/my-api/v1/edge/12345], Content-Type=[application/json], Transfer-Encoding=[chunked], Date=[Wed, 28 May 2014 05:19:43 GMT]}
```

Is my usage of `content-Location` correct to show exact URL for the resource.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. Which spec did you look at (RFC 2616 or RFC 7231-to-be), and what is your concrete question?

Comment: Exact question would be should GET response have content-location or location

Comment: Please read the relevant sections in <http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-26.html> and see whether they answer your questions. In general, you don't need to supply those.

Comment: I don't understand, this is just a single link... Where are the others, how do you want to navigate?